# Problemas con Bash - Cmder

Tags: bash, cmder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenos días, sabes como puedo quitar ese color medio amarillo de listado no me deja ver las a carpetas
estoy utilizando Bash - Cmder

Comment: Parece que usas `zsh` o `oh-my-zsh`, no? Intenta usar sólo `bash`, es decir, escribe `bash` y cuando estés usándolo, pon un `ls -la` sobre esa misma carpeta para ver qué sucede y ver el cambio de colores.

Comment: Hola, no utilizo zsh, estoy utilizando bash y oh-my-bash, probe esto ls -la e igual lo sigue pintando como la foto

Comment: Nunca he usado oh-my-bash (y creo que debería usarlo). Tengo la sospecha de que es problema de ese plugin. Quizás tiene que ver con los permisos, ya que en oh-my-zsh te pone las carpetas de color amarillo cuando tiene permisos 777. Intenta mostrar los permisos con `ls -la`

Comment: Si creo que es parte del plugins, porque creo que con oh-my-zsh no pasa eso , pero igual Gracias y encontré la solución aca https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574819/how-to-remove-dir-background-in-ls-color-output

Comment: La solución fue la siguiente 
nano  ~/.bashrc
eval "$(dircolors -p | \
    sed 's/ 4[0-9];/ 01;/; s/;4[0-9];/;01;/g; s/;4[0-9] /;01 /' | \
    dircolors /dev/stdin)"

Comment: Qué bueno que hayas encontradado la solución. Si puedes, márca tu respuesta como la aceptada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución

```
nano  ~/.bashrc

eval "$(dircolors -p | \
    sed 's/ 4[0-9];/ 01;/; s/;4[0-9];/;01;/g; s/;4[0-9] /;01 /' | \
    dircolors /dev/stdin)"
```

Dejo el link de referencia
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574819/how-to-remove-dir-background-in-ls-color-output